# Why does revoke privileges fail?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to revoke a user's privileges on a database.

```
mysql> revoke all on db_example.* from 'springuser'@'localhost';
```

And I get this error message:

```
ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements
```

and the command fails.

I'm not sure whose password the error message is refering to? Is it validating the password of the user I'm logged in as, or is it complaining that the user whose grants I'm modifying has a bad password?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does the account you use to login to MySQL have the privileges to revoke privileges

Comment: Hi, yes, I'm logged in using the root account and it has privileges `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
revoke all on db_example.* from 'rootuser'@'localhost' identified by 'mypasswd'
```

with 'mypasswd' being the password of the 'rootuser'.